# Answering indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help, I need to answer this problem[image]

I tried $\left [ ln\tfrac{1-sinx}{1+sinx}\right ]^{3}$ plug in to $\frac{2\cos x}{1-\sin ^{2}x}dx$

but i think it's quite incorrect and I'm missing something, can someone told me the correct first step on answering or re writing this problem,? I'm struggling to start and continue this one,

Thank you in advance...

Comment: My first thought would probably be trying to substitute u=sinx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$D\bigg(\ln(\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x})\bigg)=\frac{-2}{\cos x}$$

Comment: ahhh Thank you! I tried answering it all over again and my final answer is $-\frac{1}{4}log^{4}(\frac{1-sinx}{1+sinx})+c$   is it correct?? Thanks for the HINT!! hehe

Comment: @Jerwell Yes its correct! You can also check your answers using wolframalpha!!

Comment: Thanks mate! Will check that their as well. have a nice day! stay safe mate! cheers!!!